# SQL Case statement to join tables

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I working on three tables with following columns:

- students(name TEXT, Courseid INTEGER, score INTEGER) for example: ('TOM', 6120,85)
- courses(courseid INTEGER, name TEXT, classroom TEXT) for example: (6110, 'Science', 'LSB105')
- gradingscheme(letter TEXT, lower REAL, upper REAL) for example: ('A', 90, 100)

I am trying to join all three tables such that it includes the letter grade for each student as specified in the gradingscheme table depending upon the score from students table. I am using sqlite3 library in Python. I wrote the sql statement as follows:

```
SELECT s.name, s.courseid, c.name, c.classroom, s.score, CASE g.letter WHEN s.score BETWEEN g.upper AND g.lower
FROM students AS s, courses AS c, gradingscheme AS g
WHERE s.courseid=c.courseid
```

However, I am getting an error. Last two lines of the error are as follows:

WHERE s.courseid=c.courseid''')

sqlite3.OperationalError: near "FROM": syntax error

Please help

edited code:

```
SELECT s.name, s.courseid, c.name, c.classroom, s.score, g.letter
FROM students AS s
INNER JOIN courses AS c
ON s.courseid=c.courseid
INNER JOIN gradingscheme AS g
ON CASE g.letter WHEN s.score BETWEEN g.lower AND g.upper
```

Now I am getting the error:

ON CASE g.letter WHEN s.score BETWEEN lower AND upper''')
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "upper": syntax error

Possibly, I cannot figure out how to use CASE statement to do conditional joining

Comment: Learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I changed the code and used Inner Join now. However, i am getting the error as shown in the edited question above. I am possibly unable to figure out how to use case statement here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to overcomplicate your query with a case statement, you can just specify your join condition as `s.score > g.lower AND s.score <= g.upper`.

```
SELECT s.name, s.courseid, c.name, c.classroom, s.score, g.letter
FROM students AS s
JOIN courses AS c
ON s.courseid=c.courseid
JOIN gradingscheme AS g
ON s.score > g.lower AND s.score <= g.upper
```

Note the less-than-or-equal-to `<=` operator on the upper range, because without this people who score 100 won't be ranked at all.

Using BETWEEN is dangerous because it means different things in different databases. In sqlite, BETWEEN is inclusive of both the lower and upper range, which means a score of 90 is between 80 & 90 and is *also* between 90 & 100. You would have students with a score of 90 appearing twice with both grades using this condition. By using `> g.lower and <= g.upper`, you can specify your grading scheme as 70-80, 80-90, 90-100 safely and be sure there is no conflict/overlap because you've been explicit in your comparison operators.

Comment: Thank you very much for fine points in the code. The advice to change < to <= is important

Answer (score 0):

No case needed -- just use "and"

```
SELECT s.name, s.courseid, c.name, c.classroom, s.score, g.letter
FROM students AS s
INNER JOIN courses AS c
ON s.courseid=c.courseid
INNER JOIN gradingscheme AS g
ON s.score > g.lower AND s.score < g.upper
```

Comment: Thank you very much Hogan. I am new to coding and did not realize that it was so simple